# SEO'd iTunes Preview of App from Wrong Region

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I've recently released [UBCme](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/ubcme/id590572253) onto the app store. The problem is that I accidentally shared the [US store link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ubcme/id590572253) which doesn't have any ratings because all my users are from Canada. Thus, the top google hit for UBCme returns the US link which doesn't show the customer ratings. The first thing I did was replace all my advertisement links with the Canadian link, but I worry that it's too late.

Has anybody made this misstep before? How did you rectify it?

I feel reluctant to re-announce my app everywhere, but is it the only way I can fix this? Is there anything Apple can do to redirect pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the store is embedded in the store link and I highly doubt whether Apple would apply a redirect especially for your application. So the best course of action is to redestribute the correct link.

Users from Canada will need to buy the app from the Canadian store anyway so they will get redirected to the store with the ratings. But of course this isn't the case if you follow the link in the browser.